# how to display user define quantity on checkbox in bundel product magento2

Tags: magento2, bundle

How to display user define quantity on checkbox in bundle product magento2 ?
i want to know which file u change for j.s. if u find the answer please share your code .
[image]

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3257088/densen)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3257088/densen

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: i have just change the scenario
see in the image : https://nimb.ws/xtrEyL

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267262/user-define-quantity-checkbox-in-bundel-product-for-magento2