# user define quantity checkbox in bundel product for magento2

Tags: magento2, bundled-product

On admin side Bundle configuration for checkbox item, I need to add "User Defined Qty"  YES/No.
We had used "Kabel/BundlePlus" for Magento 1. I need the same functionality for Magento 2. Is anyone customized or have an extension for this.

[image]
[image]

Comment: in magento2 there is no user define option in  multiple select.
in radio button you have user define option by default. i also manage my query using radio button.

Comment: Can you solve this issue?

Comment: Yes. I have modified the code.

Answer (score 1):

after 4 days working on this here's my solution for you.

you must override `bundle-user-defined-checkbox.js` in "Magento_Bundle/view/adminhtml/web/js/components"

to do that create `requirejs-config.js` in "app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml"

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Bundle/js/components/bundle-user-defined-checkbox': 'Vendor_Module/js/bundle-user-defined-checkbox'
    }
}
};
```

then create `bundle-user-defined-checkbox.js` in "app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/web/js"

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/single-checkbox'
], function (Checkbox) {
    'use strict';

    return Checkbox.extend({
        defaults: {
            listens: {
                inputType: 'onInputTypeChange'
            }
        },

        /**
         * Handler for "inputType" property
         *
         * @param {String} data
         */
        onInputTypeChange: function (data) {
            data === 'multi' ?
                this.clear()
                    .visible(false) :
                this.visible(true);
        }
    });
});
```

clear cache and run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and checkbox will be added to admin panel

Comment: Thanks for the code. in fact, I build the module for this as this needs to work on the frontend side also. let us know if anyone wants this.

Comment: @PratikKamani Can you please post the code or provided reference link? I need similar functionality in magento2 site.